# CakePHP Form GET-Method URL

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I want to create a DB-Entry with an create form.

> controller/create/1

If the method is called without an ID, the Controller renders a different View (Step1) with a different form where the User has to Select an ID.

Now i want this form to call the given URL as shown above.

I tried in the view: $this->Form->create('...', array(

> 'type' => 'get'

but this gives me an URL like this:

> controller/create/?id=5

Does anyone know how to adapt the URL?

Comment: The point is, that you send 1 in the first form and 5 in the second.

Comment: it's not about the ID. ITs about the URL Pattern.
i want: `/controller/create/ID`
i dont want: `/controller/create/?id=ID`

Comment: Ok, check this out: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html